# Cassandra/Pycassa: Getting random rows

Tags: python, cassandra, uuid, pycassa

Is there a possibility to retrieve random rows from Cassandra (using it with Python/Pycassa)?

Update: With random rows I mean *randomly* selected rows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do this by making a `get_range` request with a random `start` key (just a random string), and a `row_count` of 1.

From memory, I think the `finish` key would need to be the same as `start`, so that the query 'wraps around' the keyspace; this would normally return *all* rows, but the `row_count` will limit that.

Haven't tried it but this should ensure you get a single result without having to know exact row keys.

Comment: As I can tell this will return random rows, but always the same... Guess there's no easy solution for this using Cassandra...

Comment: You would need to keep calling `get_range` with a new random start key each time...this should choose a row from a random point on the keyspace ring.

Comment: Hi, I'm a newbie to Cassandra too, but I have a bad feeling about this answer. Would this give you a uniform distribution? It seems like depending on how your keys are spread out, some rows might be substantially more likely to be selected than others.

Comment: The key will be hashed by Cassandra, so this should give a good distribution of tokens around the keyspace - this is part of the design. You'd need to make sure your input keys don't repeat too often though - I'd suggest using Math.Random() to generate some bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by random rows.  If you mean random access rows, then sure you can do it very easily:

```
import pycassa.pool
import pycassa.columnfamily

pool = pycassa.pool.ConnectionPool('keyspace', ['localhost:9160']
cf = pycassa.columnfamily.ColumnFamily(pool, 'cfname')
row = cf.get('row_key')
```

That will give you any row.  If you mean that you want a randomly selected row, I don't think you'd be able to do that very easily without knowing what the keys are.  You could generate an index row and then select a random column from that and use that to grab a row from another column family.  Basically, you'd need to create a new row where each column value, was a row key from the column family from which you are trying to select a row.  Then you could grab a column randomly from that row and you have the key to a random row.

I don't think pycassa offers any support to grab a random, non-indexed row.

Answer (score 0):

This works for my case:

```
ini = random.randint(0, 999999999)
rows = col_fam.get_range(str(ini), row_count=1, column_count=0,filter_empty=False)
```

You'll have to adapt to your row key type (string in my case)