# select randow row from cassandra

Tags: python, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE prosfiles (
  name_file text,
  beginpros timestamp,
  humandate timestamp,
  lastpros timestamp,
  originalname text,
  pros int,
  uploaded int,
  uploader text,
  PRIMARY KEY (name_file)
)
CREATE INDEX prosfiles_pros_idx ON prosfiles (pros);
```

In this table I keep the location of several csv files wich are processed by a python script, as I have several scripts running at the same time processing those files, I use this table to keep control and avoid two scripts start processing the same file at the same time (in the 'pros' colum 0 means the file has not being processed, 1 for processed files and 1010 for files that are currently being processed by another script)

each file runs the following query to pick the file to process:

```
"select name_file from prosfiles where pros = 0 limit 1"
```

but this always returns the first row of the files with that condition

I would like to run a query that returns a randow row from all the ones with pros = 0.

In mysql I've used "order by rand()" but in cassandra I don't know how to random sort the results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cassandra/Pycassa: Getting random rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566060/cassandra-pycassa-getting-random-rows)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that you're using Cassandra as a queue and [it's not the best usage pattern for it](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-like-datasets), use rabbitmq/sqs/any-other-queue-service. Also Cassandra does not support sorting at all, and it's done with the idea that:

- sort will require a lot of computations inside database if you are trying to sort 1B of rows.
- sort is not an easy task in distributed environment: you have to ask all nodes holding the data to perform it.

But if you know what you are doing, you can revisit your database schema to be more suitable for this type of workload:

- split your source table into two different tables: first one with full file information and the second one with the queue itself containing only ids of files to process.
- your worker process reads random row from `queue` table (see below how to read ~random row from cassandra by primary key)
- worker deletes target id from `queue` and updates your targets table with processing information.

This way of doing things will lead you to possible errors:

- multiple workers can get the same target at once.
- if you have a lot of workers and targets, Cassandra's compaction process will kill the performance of your DIY queue.

To read a pseudo-random row from table by it's primary key you can use this query: `select * from some_table where token(id_column)>some_random_long_value limit 1`, but it will also have it's cons:

- if you have a small set of targets, it will sporadically return empty result because your `some_random_long_value` will be higher than token of any existing key.